The generated table in the code doesnt read the csv file causing the table to show no data
The code generated a table but the table shows no value instead of reading it from the csv file.
import csv

# Load the dataset
file_path = '/Users/brosis/Downloads/AvgHouseholdElectricity.csv'

# Accept user input for the year
year_input = input("Enter the year (between 2010 and 2023): ")

# List of regions and dwelling types for formatting the output
regions = ["Central", "North", "West", "North East", "East"]
dwelling_types = ["Private Apartments and Condominiums","1-room / 2-room","3-room","4-room","5-room and Executive","Landed Properties"]

# Initialize a dictionary to store the minimum consumption for each region and dwelling type
min_consumption = {region: {dwelling: str('in f') for dwelling in dwelling_types} for region in regions}

# Open the CSV file and read data
with open(file_path, mode='r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csv_reader)  # Skip the header row

    # Process each row in the dataset
    for row in csv_reader:
        year, region, dwelling_type, consumption = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]

        # Filter data by the selected year
        if year == year_input:
            try:
                consumption_value = float(consumption)  # Convert consumption to float
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Skipping invalid consumption value: {consumption} for row: {row}")
                continue

            # Initialize the nested dictionary if necessary
            if dwelling_type not in min_consumption:
                min_consumption[dwelling_type] = {region: float('inf') for region in regions}

            # Update the minimum consumption for the corresponding region
            if region in min_consumption[dwelling_type]:
                min_consumption[dwelling_type][region] = min(min_consumption[dwelling_type][region], consumption_value)

# Prepare output for the table
print(f"\nRegional Dwelling Type Analysis for year {year_input}")
print("____________________________________________________________________________________________")
print(f"|{'':<35}| {'|'.join([region.center(10) for region in regions])}|")
print("____________________________________________________________________________________________")

# Output the minimum consumption for each dwelling type
for dwelling_type in dwelling_types:
    # Create a row with minimum consumption or 'no data' if no data
    row_values = [
        f"{min_consumption.get(dwelling_type, {}).get(region, 'No Data'):>10}" 
        for region in regions
    ]
    print(f"|{dwelling_type:<35}| {'|'.join(row_values)}|")
    print("____________________________________________________________________________________________")


I tried making so many trials and errors to debug it but still cant fix it. Tried using chatgpt to help to look for errors but still not able to help me. Need help for assignment in Uni very important. Would greatly appreciate for any help.
Below is my assignment question.
enter image description here
Below is the csv file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R30GtaLLiZxP0uHsfcAt6CIDc4j9XDnF/view?usp=sharing

Can you share the CSV?

Here is the csv file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R30GtaLLiZxP0uHsfcAt6CIDc4j9XDnF/view?usp=sharing

See my amended answer

You need to make up your mind. Is region nested in dwelling or the other way around?
min_consumption = {region: {dwelling: str('in f') for dwelling in dwelling_types} for region in regions}

Here you have dwelling nested within region.
And later, you try to access like this:
f"{min_consumption.get(dwelling_type, {}).get(region, 'No Data'):>10}"

This won't work because you're trying to access the dwelling first, and then the region.
You could, say change the initialization to:
min_consumption = {dwelling_type: {region: float('inf') for region in regions} for dwelling_type in dwelling_types}


You have 5 regions and 6 dwelling types. Create a dictionary keyed on dwelling type with each value being a list of 5 float values that correspond to the known regions.
In the OP, each row is being parsed incorrectly. The column order differs from what's implied in the code.
This will process the file correctly:
import csv

year = input("Enter the year (between 2010 and 2023): ")

regions = ["", "Central", "North", "West", "North East", "East"]
t = "|{:<35}|{:>10.2f}|{:>10.2f}|{:>10.2f}|{:>10.2f}|{:>10.2f}|"
fr = "|{:<35}|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|{:>10}|".format(*regions)
w = len(fr)
ul = "\u2014" * w

dwelling_types = {
    "Private Apartments and Condominiums": [float("inf")] * 5,
    "1-room / 2-room": [float("inf")] * 5,
    "3-room": [float("inf")] * 5,
    "4-room": [float("inf")] * 5,
    "5-room and Executive": [float("inf")] * 5,
    "Landed Properties": [float("inf")] * 5,
}

def match_region(r):
    t = r.split()
    if t[-1] == "Region":
        r = " ".join(t[:-1])
    return regions.index(r) - 1
        
with open("AvgHouseholdElectricity.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
        dwelling_type, yy, _, region, _, consumption = map(str.strip, row)
        if yy == year:
            try:
                consumption_value = float(consumption)
                dt = dwelling_types[dwelling_type]
                i = match_region(region)
                dt[i] = min(dt[i], consumption_value)
            except (ValueError, KeyError):
                print(
                    f"Skipping invalid consumption value, unknown dwelling type or region for row {row}"
                )
            continue

print(ul)
print(f"Regional Dwelling Type Analysis for year {year}".center(w))
print(ul)
print(fr)
for k, v in dwelling_types.items():
    print(t.format(k, *v))
print(ul)


Is it possible if you could explain the coding as I have only learnt basic python

But why didn't you use dictionary

@Winnie If you look very closely you will see how a dictionary has been utilised in this answer. Did you run this code? Did it work for you?

Yes I ran the code and works well. Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciate it!
